# Android listView in Fragment crashes on click

Tags: java, android, listview

So my list is populated with a few items, however it crashes whenever I click any of the items. This happens regardless of weather I have a click listener or not. I've looked for a solution online, but haven't been able to figure out what's causing this, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    songList = getSongList();
    Collections.sort(songList);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_layout, container, false);
    songListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listSongs);
    songListView.setAdapter(new SongAdapter(this.getActivity(), songList));

    songListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

logcat:
http://pastebin.com/Zga14R5e

here's getSongList method:

```
public ArrayList<Song> getSongList() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = this.getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (musicCursor != null) {
        if (musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String songName = musicCursor
                        .getString(musicCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));

                String path = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                String artistName = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                String albumName = musicCursor.getString(musicCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));

                Song song = new Song(songName, artistName, path, albumName);
                songList.add(song);

            } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());


        }

    }

    return songList;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat ?

Comment: Unless you post the logcat output nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: oops, logcat now posted

Comment: The error comes from `getSongList()` method. Please post it as well. Oh, sorry, that's an old error. Now, I guess you specified `songPicked` in onClick event in an XML layout, but didn't provide java implementation. From the stacktrace I would say your `MainActivity` needs a method with a signature: `public void songPicked(View view)`.

Comment: thank you so much. I had copied and pasted from another XML layout and that was the issue. thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll post it as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace tells that `songPicked(View)` method was specified in the XML layout but wasn't found in `MainActivity`. Thus the solution is to either implement it in the `MainActivity`'s code or to remove the corresponding `onClick` attribute from the `View` in the XML layout.